# How to do a facebook photo preview style using React + React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wan't to do something similar to what Facebook does when showing photos on your news feed, example:

If I'm on my news feed, if i click on a photo, it opens a modal, and changes the URL, but the back-content remains the same in case I want to close that modal.

In case I send this URL to someone else, it shows a different page for the photo, without the news on the background.

Basically, when I click on the link button, I wan't to show my data on top of what the user is seeing (and change the URL), in case he refreshes the screen, I want to show it in a different way, like a special page for that data.

Any ideas on how to do this using react + react-router?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout the [Pinterest example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/pinterest/app.js) in the react router repo. It basically does exactly what you're [asking for](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/pinterest/app.js#L91).   Two different views depending on the router state/how the user got to the page.

You can pull the react-router repo and follow [these instructions](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples) if you want to see the example locally.  I couldn't find the examples hosted anywhere online.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll check those :)